# regex match anything between {esbmsg:header:xxxxxx}

Tags: regex

How to match  anything between `{esbmsg:header:` and `}`

like `xxxxxx` could be any string `{esbmsg:header:xxxxxx}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
{esbmsg:header:([^}]*)}
```

Where `[^}]*` matches everything that is not `}` character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
{esbmsg:header:(.*)}
```

It will also allow you to have any character in value.

Comment: Make the quantifier relucatant - `.*?`

Comment: ? is not required because if i add it then it will match only {esbmsg:header:xxxxxx} of {esbmsg:header:xxxxxx}}dfgfd}

Comment: Exactly. That is why it is required. Perhaps we don't have information whether OP wants to read till the last `}` or the first. But I would guess it to be first.

Comment: I would assume that OP wants till end. Because everything must be allowed until explicitly restricted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to capture only the content of your expression (the "xxxxx" part) the best approach is to use positive look ahead:

> (?<={esbmsg:header:)[^}]+

Depending on how your content looks you might have to tweak the [^}] part. For further information on regex (or a detailed explanation of the expression above) I recommend the following:

[Regex reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/484310/Regex-Quick-Reference)

[Regex tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)